# Whats the difference between the two command lines? (SegFault)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I have written a code that maps to a shared memory location,so that the first program opens a shared memory block and stores some data in it.And the second program reads the shared data.

Whats the difference between the two command lines:

**1.**

```
 if(argc<2)
 {
     printf("USAGE:%s text-to-share\n",argv[0]);
 }
```

This code gives me a Segmentation Fault if I run it without the second argument.
However it works fine when I enter in some data.

**2.**

```
 if(argc<2)
    return printf("USAGE:%s text-to-share\n",argv[0]);
```

This one serves my purpose.

But I fail to understand the difference between the two.
I'm a novice.For me the two are same,because ideally they should have the same output.
Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why first statment giving you segmentation fault,in C it name of the program which you are executing,so it should be absolutely fine.I am able to execute this testcase properly

```
int main(int argc,char ** argv){
    if(argc<2)
     {
         printf("USAGE:%s text-to-share\n",argv[0]);
     }
    return 0;
 }
```

it output :

```
USAGE:./prog text-to-share
```

except you are doing something wrong in the code executed before this.

Comment: I wasn't returning 0.That was the problem. Thanks. +1

Comment: You shouldn't return 0 when there's an error (invalid parameters) because 0 indicates success; @Pavitar, you should return non-zero inside the if statement.

Answer (score 3):

The two are obviously *not* the same:

```
printf("USAGE:%s text-to-share\n",argv[0]);        // From example 1
return printf("USAGE:%s text-to-share\n",argv[0]); // From example 2
```

The second line has something the first line does not:  a return statement.

Comment: @James McNellis-Can you tell me what that 'something' is?

Comment: @James McNellis -But both of them,should do the same thing,right?(Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: @Pavitar, no. Since you're not returning in the first one, the code will continue and still dereference `argv[1]`.  Also, it's not really meaningful to return the result of `printf`; that's the number of characters outputted.  Instead, return a fixed error code (e.g. 1).

Comment: @Pavitar:  No.  In the first example, the function continues executing after calling `printf`.  In the second example, it returns to its caller and does not continue executing.

Comment: Thank you guys.@Matthew Flaschen- So what do you suggest?If I use (eg.1),how do I avoid the SegFault?

Comment: `main()` is supposed to return 0 on success and non-zero on failure. That convention is solidly established in *nix, and enshrined in the C standards as well. The only non-zero value that the standard requires your platform to allow is 1. For widest portability, return 1 (or call `exit(1)`) on failure. On *nix platforms in practice, you are allowed to return any value up to 127 so you can distinguish between kinds of failure.